# Deleted property showing up in debug still?

Tags: c#

In my current project, I have deleted a property that I no longer want. This property is named "`Customer_Part_Revision`". However, This property still shows up when I run debug and inspect an object of type Line.

[image: Property List]

[image: Debug Info]

And Finally My Search Results for "entire solution" do not find any reference to "`Customer_Part_Revision`".

Comment: Could it be that you're debugging an older version of your executable instead of the latest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your struct defined in a separate project (even if it's within the same solution)?

If so, you may need to update the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is compiled into a DLL, which may not have been updated. Have you tried runnning "Clean" and then "Rebuild"

Comment: Just gave it a shot, still coming up with the same situation.

Comment: In the bin folder of the project, are there any PDB files? Try removing those and rebuilding